# How to start a loop from a specific index of a list in python?

Tags: python

I have this csv file with this data:

```
1 this_is_x, this_is_y
2 info about x, info about y
2 10,20
3 10,10
4 5,10

with open('my_file.csv') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
next(csv_reader)
for row in csv_reader:
    x, y = row
    list_x.append(x)
    list_y.append(y)
```

How to start the loop from 10,20 for appending x and y in list_x and list_y without the first two rows?

Comment: Do you know the purpose of that line `next(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you repeat the `next()` statement, one more line will be skipped at the beginning of the file:

```
    import csv

    list_x = []
    list_y = []

    with open('my_file.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        next(csv_reader)  # skip header line
        next(csv_reader)  # skip second line
        for x, y in csv_reader:
            list_x.append(x)
            list_y.append(y)
```

Note how you can avoid using intermediate variables while reading in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, *csv.reader()* method returns a **reader** object *which iterates over lines in the given CSV file*, which is **not subscriptable**, and that means **you can't slice it**. You can avoid the first two lines by creating a list from *csv.reader()* returned object and then, just slice it like [2:] to abandon the first two lines of csv file.

Code is given below:

```py
import csv

list_x = []
list_y = []

with open('so_test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for x, y in list(csv_reader)[2:]:
        list_x.append(x)
        list_y.append(y)

print(list_x)
print(list_y)
```

And the output is:

```
['10', '10', '5']
['20', '10', '10']
```

[P.S.]: This code is tested in **python 3.6.8 version**.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.